# Трансляция экрана в фб

Tags: linux, facebook

Всем привет. Как в OS Linux транслировать экран в фейсбук? Хочу сделать прямую трансляцию показывая экран рабочего стола вместо вэб камеры, а затем эту трансляцию в совместный просмотр.

Comment: Ищите программы, чаще всего внутри они будут звать ffmpeg.

Comment: OBS Studio. . .

Comment: Спасибо. OBS Studio отлично подходит для этих целей!